# Add \cite to Tufte style thesis

Tags: bibliographies, citing, tufte

I'm writing my thesis using the tamplate Tufte style, it's my first document in Latex. I tried to add the first `\cite` but I'm having problems.

Here is the code:

**main.tex:**

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% uncomment this line if you prefer colored hyperlinks (e.g., for onscreen viewing)
\hypersetup{colorlinks} 

% get chapter and section numbers {is the depth}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Book metadata
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{A Tufte-Style Book\thanks{Thanks to Edward R.~Tufte for his inspiration.}}
\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers}
\publisher{Publisher of This Book}

%\usepackage{microtype}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Just some sample text
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For nicely typeset tabular material
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For graphics / images
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, totalheight=\textheight, keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The fancyvrb package lets us customize the 
% formatting of verbatim environments.  
% We use a slightly smaller font.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prints argument within hanging parentheses (i.e., parentheses that take
% up no horizontal space).  Useful in tabular environments.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\hangp}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{(}#1\makebox[0pt][l]{)}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prints an asterisk that takes up no horizontal space.
% Useful in tabular environments.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\hangstar}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prints a trailing space in a smart way.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xspace}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Some shortcuts for Tufte's book titles.  
% The lowercase commands will produce the initials of the book title in italics.  
% The all-caps commands will print out the full title of the book in italics.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}

\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}

% other useful code...

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    %\input{./frontespizio/frontespizio} 
    \input{./ringraziamenti/ringraziamenti}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables   

    \mainmatter
    \input{./capitoli/0}
    \input{./capitoli/1}

    % bibliografia
    \bibliography{./bibliografia/bibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

    %\printindex
\end{document}
```

**1.text**:

```
In the book\cite{ColinWare_InformationVisualization} bla bla bla
% other lines
@book{ColinWare_InformationVisualization,
    author = {Colin Ware},
    title = {Information visualization - Perception for design},
    date = {2012},
    edition = {3},
}
```

**bibliografia/bibliography.bib**

```
@BOOK{ColinWare_InformationVisualization,
    author = {Colin Ware},
    title = {Information visualization: Perception for design},
    year = {2012},
    publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann},
    month = {June},
    edition = {Third},
    isbn = {978-0123814647}
}
```

I get this error:

```
riga 57: Missing $ inserted. @book{ColinWare_
riga 62: Extra }, or forgotten $. }
riga 188: Missing $ inserted.
: shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
: Marginpar on page 11 moved.
riga 20: Citation `ColinWare_InformationVisualization' undefined
: Marginpar on page 12 moved.
riga 22: Overfull \hbox (5.29193pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 31: Reference `fig:fullfigCatCenter' on page 12 undefined
: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.
riga 41: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
riga 57: Overfull \hbox (2.93614pt too wide) in paragraph
riga 57: Overfull \hbox (0.60222pt too wide) in paragraph
: There were undefined citations.
: There were undefined references.
```

[image]

Thanks!

## EDIT

I eliminated this code inside `1.tex`:

```
@book{ColinWare_InformationVisualization,
    author = {Colin Ware},
    title = {Information visualization - Perception for design},
    date = {2012},
    edition = {3},
}
```

but now there is nothing in the margin, just the number and not the title of the book.

[image]

Furthermore, the bibliography at the bottom of the thesis doesn't appear either.

Comment: The `@book{ColinWare_InformationVisualization,` entry does not belong into the `1.tex` file, it belongs into `bibliografia/bibliography.bib`. Removing `@book{ColinWare_InformationVisualization,...}` from the `.tex` should fix the problem.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, now there is no longer that problem but nothing appears in the margin. I modified the main message with more details.

Comment: Please update your entire code and the warning and error messages you get. They should be different now. Did you run BibTeX (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)?

Comment: Solved as in 'it works now'?